# Diagnosing AccessViolationException in optimized compiled code

Tags: vb.net, optimization, crash

I have a large vb.net x86 project that is running in VS2015 and .Net 4.5.2

When it is compiled and run in debug without optimization then it works ok. However if I compile and run it in Release mode with optimization turned on then I get a variety of exceptions at the same innocuous line of code. I have tried debugging it in release mode but the breakpoints are unreliable. Also the very act of debugging it seems to modify the exception. Also if I change the code (for example putting a MsgBox in to display information) then the problem can go away. For example I changed an Arraylist to a List(Of Control) and the problem no longer occurred where it did before but now moved elsewhere.

I have received all of the following at different times:
AccessViolationException,
NullReferenceException (somewhere deep within .Net classes)
and FatalExecutionEngineError

The exception detail in the AccessViolationException tells nothing except that "this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt". The stack trace is meaningless and there is no description of what it thought was at the invalid memory address.

I also cannot find any meaningful detail about what Optimization in the compiler actually does - one solution might be to turn Optimization off but I don't understand what the benefit / negative effect is of doing this.

Is the Optimization unreliable? How can one possibly try and ascertain what is happening?

The only unmanaged code we use is some calls to get Icons related to file extensions - which are then cloned into managed objects and the unmanaged memory destroyed. This is pretty standard and the same API has been used since 1.1 and through 4.5.2 for 10 years without this occurring before.

I cannot create a small project that reproduces the issue

Here's the code we use for extracting icons as it's the only potential cause I have right now. It was borrowed from elsewhere and I can't really tell whether it's as good as it should be:

```
Public Class IconExtractor

<Flags()> Private Enum SHGFI
    SmallIcon = &H1
    LargeIcon = &H0
    Icon = &H100
    DisplayName = &H200
    Typename = &H400
    SysIconIndex = &H4000
    UseFileAttributes = &H10
End Enum

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Private Structure SHFILEINFO
    Public hIcon As IntPtr
    Public iIcon As Integer
    Public dwAttributes As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst:=260)> Public szDisplayName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst:=80)> Public szTypeName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal B As Boolean)
        hIcon = IntPtr.Zero
        iIcon = 0
        dwAttributes = 0
        szDisplayName = vbNullString
        szTypeName = vbNullString
    End Sub
End Structure

Private Declare Auto Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "shell32" (
ByVal pszPath As String, ByVal dwFileAttributes As Integer,
ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, ByVal cbFileInfo As Integer, ByVal uFlags As SHGFI) As Integer

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function DestroyIcon(ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Public Shared Sub GetIconsForFile(ByVal rstrFileName As String, ByRef rzSmallIcon As Icon, ByRef rzLargeIcon As Icon)
    Dim zFileInfo As New SHFILEINFO(True)
    Dim cbSizeInfo As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(zFileInfo)
    Dim flags As SHGFI = SHGFI.Icon Or SHGFI.UseFileAttributes Or SHGFI.SmallIcon
    SHGetFileInfo(rstrFileName, 256, zFileInfo, cbSizeInfo, flags)
    ' Use clone so we can destroy immediately
    rzSmallIcon = DirectCast(Icon.FromHandle(zFileInfo.hIcon).Clone, Icon)
    DestroyIcon(zFileInfo.hIcon)

    zFileInfo = New SHFILEINFO(True)
    cbSizeInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(zFileInfo)
    flags = SHGFI.Icon Or SHGFI.UseFileAttributes Or SHGFI.LargeIcon
    SHGetFileInfo(rstrFileName, 256, zFileInfo, cbSizeInfo, flags)
    ' Use clone so we can destroy immediately
    rzLargeIcon = DirectCast(Icon.FromHandle(zFileInfo.hIcon).Clone, Icon)
    DestroyIcon(zFileInfo.hIcon)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across the solution to this by chance.

I was reading this documentation of SHGETFILEINFO 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179(v=vs.85).aspx
and found that it said in the remarks: *You should call this function from a background thread. Failure to do so could cause the UI to stop responding*

It isn't clear **why** you should call it from a background thread nor is it clear what "stop responding" might actually manifest itself as.

However it seemed this was fairly likely what was causing the problem and so I refactored to execute the api call under a separate thread. This has certainly seemed to work. Many of the examples on the internet of SHGETFILEINFO do not seem to consider the separate thread requirement.

I reproduce the whole refactored code here:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading

''' <summary>
''' Retrieves the small and large icons registered for a filename based on the file's extension
''' </summary>
Public Class FileIcons

    Private mFileName As String
    Private mSmallIconHandle As IntPtr
    Private mSmallIcon As Icon
    Private mLargeIconHandle As IntPtr
    Private mLargeIcon As Icon

    Public Sub New(ByVal rFileName As String)
        mFileName = rFileName

        Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf GetIconsForFile)
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        t.Start()
        t.Join()

        ' Use clone so we can destroy immediately
        mSmallIcon = DirectCast(Icon.FromHandle(mSmallIconHandle).Clone, Icon)
        DestroyIcon(mSmallIconHandle)

        ' Use clone so we can destroy immediately
        mLargeIcon = DirectCast(Icon.FromHandle(mLargeIconHandle).Clone, Icon)
        DestroyIcon(mLargeIconHandle)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property SmallIcon As Icon
        Get
            Return mSmallIcon
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property LargeIcon As Icon
        Get
            Return mLargeIcon
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub GetIconsForFile()
        ' Go and extract the small and large icons
        ' Full filename must be < MAX_PATH - which is 260 chars in .Net (apparently) though a file path/length of 256 also causes an error. 
        ' Otherwise SHGetFileInfo gets nothing, Icon.FromHandle then gives "System.ArgumentException: The Win32 handle you passed to Icon is invalid or of the wrong type."
        ' This needs to be stopped in the calling code, or the resulting error trapped 

        Dim zFileInfo As New SHFILEINFO(True)
        Dim cbSizeInfo As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(zFileInfo)
        Dim flags As SHGFI = SHGFI.Icon Or SHGFI.UseFileAttributes Or SHGFI.SmallIcon
        SHGetFileInfo(mFileName, 256, zFileInfo, cbSizeInfo, flags)
        mSmallIconHandle = zFileInfo.hIcon

        zFileInfo = New SHFILEINFO(True)
        cbSizeInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(zFileInfo)
        flags = SHGFI.Icon Or SHGFI.UseFileAttributes Or SHGFI.LargeIcon
        SHGetFileInfo(mFileName, 256, zFileInfo, cbSizeInfo, flags)
        mLargeIconHandle = zFileInfo.hIcon
    End Sub

#Region "WinAPI"
    <Flags()> Private Enum SHGFI
        SmallIcon = &H1
        LargeIcon = &H0
        Icon = &H100
        DisplayName = &H200
        Typename = &H400
        SysIconIndex = &H4000
        UseFileAttributes = &H10
    End Enum

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Private Structure SHFILEINFO
        Public hIcon As IntPtr
        Public iIcon As Integer
        Public dwAttributes As Integer
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst:=260)> Public szDisplayName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst:=80)> Public szTypeName As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal B As Boolean)
            hIcon = IntPtr.Zero
            iIcon = 0
            dwAttributes = 0
            szDisplayName = vbNullString
            szTypeName = vbNullString
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Private Declare Auto Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "shell32" (
        ByVal pszPath As String,
        ByVal dwFileAttributes As Integer,
        ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO,
        ByVal cbFileInfo As Integer,
        ByVal uFlags As SHGFI) As Integer

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Private Shared Function DestroyIcon(ByVal hIcon As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function
#End Region

End Class
```